# How to get suggestions for compilation errors in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

One of the features I love the most about Eclipse is that is shows you suggestions for compilation errors just by hovering over the error with the mouse. For instance, if I make a class implement an interface, it'll automatically offer me to add the unimplemented methods. Or if I use a variable I haven't created yet, it'll offer me to declare it.

Is there such a functionality in Intellij? If so, how can I turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your cursor on the underlined part of code which shows an error, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and pop-up menu with available quick-fixes will be shown as illustrated in the screenshot below.

[image]

This also works for other types of inspections, such as warnings, not just compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks for the size 48 font, I needed it that large!

Comment: @vikingsteve That's actually size 12 font in the screenshot, just taken on Retina display so it appears larger... i wasn't in the mood to resize the screenshot :)